# Sort array by value and store in variable

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$array = array(5,4,6,8,5,3,4,6,1);
```

I want to sort `$array` like `asort` does, but the problem is that `asort` is a function and its product can't be stored in a variable.

How can I do something like this?:

```
$array = array(5,4,6,8,5,3,4,6,1);
$sorted_array = asort($array);
```

**Edit:** I also want `$array` to keep its original order.

Comment: Their is no need to store the result of `asort` because it is sorted inside `$array` and now you can directly access sorted array using `$array`.

Comment: Yes, but I also lose my original order.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this for maintaining `$array` in its original order

```
$array = array(5,4,6,8,5,3,4,6,1);
$sorted_array = $array;
asort($sorted_array);
```

Output

http://codepad.viper-7.com/8E78Fo

Answer (score 2):

```
 $orignal_array = array(5,4,6,8,5,3,4,6,1);
 $copied_array = $orignal_array;

 asort($copied_array);
 $sorted_array = $copied_array;

 not the most efficient way to do it though :(
```

Comment: I should've mentioned that I want `$array` to keep its original order.

Comment: I still think there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Sort it first and then assign it

```
asort($array);
$sorted_array = $array
```